# How can I create a MongoDB user from my NodeJS application with authentication enabled?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security

I use MongoDB with Mongoose on a remote server, I connect via my NodeJS application like this:

```
mongodb://3.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/test
```

This works fine, I also set the `authorization = enabled` in the `mongod.conf` file on my server and create a admin. Know I want to connect to my MongoDB with the URL below and create a new user, but when I do this I get an authentication error.

I know that I also can connect via authentication like this

```
mongodb://admin:pw@3.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/test?authsource=admin
```

When its no problem to create a new user, but thats not secure (?)

I want that a random user, can create user on my MongoDB and after that he can authentication to it, to get read and wirte permissions. For me it makes no sense that a random user connect as a admin to create a new user. 
Am I thinking something wrong ?

This is how I create a user via my NodeJS app:

```
    exports.create = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.mail && !req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "User conntent can not be empty"
        });
    }

    const user = new User({
        mail: req.body.mail,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

    user.save()
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || " Some error occurred while creating user."
            });
        });
};
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're asking, but... I can't imagine why you would allow a random user to create a database user account. This seems like a very large security issue. This is something your app should do, not an end-user. No outside user should ever have such access to your database. As for security of your connection string: it's secure because the connection is secure. But you should never be giving those credentials out. Once you do, you've basically given away your database.

Comment: could you share your server code where your mongodb connection is located?

Comment: I want to impl. a sign in/ sign up process, so a random user need the permission to create an account, to get additional permissions and can use the application full.

Comment: @developKinberg - provide this through a web app, an API, etc. Do *not* give any such direct-connection permission on a database. Ever. This is Security 101 stuff.

Comment: @DavidMakogon can you explained it more ? I write a REST Api for my MongoDB and from my Client-Side I connect only to the Api and the Api connect to the MongoDB

Comment: What David is trying to say, is when you create a mongodb user, it is not **your** mongodb any more. It's **their** mongodb. If you write a REST API for **your** mongodb - create users on application level (like a collection of registered users) and use serverside configured mongodb user credentials to query database from your application. mongodb user != rest api user. The former is your trusted application, the later is your untrusted http clients.

Comment: @AlexBlex okay so should I create with my admin account a new **db account** what have read/write permissions for let say **test db**. And this **db account** can I use to create user for the **collection** users ? So every **app user** logging in with the same **db account** and then I can use my functions like validate if the user exist or not, register a new user etc..

Comment: yep, that's the most common scenario.

Comment: Right - @AlexBlex was far more eloquent than I was (I blame lack of coffee). You can dole out user accounts if you wish, with specific limited credentials as you see fit. By the way: If all operations go directly through your app, consider the idea that you might not need to create *any* users accounts, other than your app's user account, and manage all access through the app. Once you give an external user access to your database, they can use (or abuse) it, eating up resources that you didn't plan for, etc. Your app tier should handle all user traffic (and it can log it, block it, etc).

Comment: @DavidMakogon but when I don't create an **db account**, I cant use the authentication function from MongoDB (?), I only use it for more security (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/). And yeah the next questions I would ask myself, how can I prevent it, for example a user delete other users, create trash or manipulate data. I am very new in this topic, but I will figure it out.

Comment: @developKinberg - You should still create an account, and still use auth (an open database is just asking to be hacked). But that should be an account specifically for your app. One account. Not an account per user, unless there's some very specific need. And use that authenticated account for your app tier to talk with the database. Anyway - this has now turned into a discussion, which Stack Overflow really isn't for. Hopefully you've gotten some good ideas, and can see why the original question, as written, is off-topic...

Comment: @DavidMakogon yep your right, but the comments help me by my problem and answers some questions